# javascript code for resizing the div

Tags: javascript, css, json, jsp

This is my jsp code actually this is hidden div i want move the this div form one tab to another tab according to onclick event on the tabs

```
<div id="addprojectname" style="-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #AAAAAA #AAAAAA;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: none solid solid;
    border-width: medium 2px 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #AAAAAA;
    display:none;
    width: 328px;">
<form name="frm" action="linkBean.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden"  id="sl_category" name="sl_no_cat" >
<table style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 8px;">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">
 <a onclick= "hidewindows('addprojectname');" href="#"><img alt="AALPINE IT SERVICES" src="images/close.png" style="width:20px; float: right; "></a>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">
<div style="width: width:271px; color:red;" id="projectnamevalidate"></div>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Project Name<span>:</span></th><td><input type="text"  name="projectname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Category Name<span>:</span></th><td><input type="text" id="cost_category" name="category"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="float:right; padding-top:15px">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 60px;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

this is my css code

```
#addprojectname{
 float: right;
 margin-left: 214px;
 margin-top: 70px;
 position: absolute;
```

}
This is my javascript code how to change that margin value and by using the javascript code dynamically can anyone plz help thank u

```
 function projectname(id1,id2)
    {
        var userid = document.getElementById(id1).value;
        var e = document.getElementById(id2);
        var url="NameProject.do?id="+userid;
         xmlhttp.open("post", url,true);
         xmlhttp.send(null);
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
          {       
                 if(xmlhttp.status==200)
                  { 
                     var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    obj = JSON.parse(temp); 
                      if(temp!="")
                      {
                          document.getElementById("cost_category").value=document.getElementById("cost_category").innerHTML=obj.catgoryname;
                          document.getElementById("sl_category").value=document.getElementById("sl_category").innerHTML=obj.sl_no_cat;
                      }
            if(temp!="")
            {
                     if(e.style.display == 'block')
                          e.style.display = 'none';
                     else
                          e.style.display = 'block'; 
            }

            if(temp=="")
              {
                alert("!Data Not existing");
              }
              }
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
e.style.marginLeft=myMarginValue;
```

That should allow you to change the margin setting as requested.  I'm not sure it will achieve the result you desire, but it will achieve the result you asked for...

Comment: from where i will pass the mymarginValue

Comment: the tabs are in the  loop how i will pass the magine value